# what does it mean when we echo javascript

Tags: php, javascript, echo

I am not able to figure out what we really mean when we echo javascript.
Does it mean; the function inside script will execute inevitably?
I mean, will it execute with out even being called?
I've seen long scripts that seem to include a complete page inside an echo statement.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
blah blah blah
});
</script>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is how you print output in PHP, it doesn't do anything special otherwise.

You can often see examples like yours in poorly organized, messy code. Like you say:

> I've seen long scripts that seem to include a complete page inside an echo statement.

People get into a bad habit of "echoing" everything, rather than, in your case, using an external javascript file, or learning to break into or out of a PHP block for view logic.

```
<p>This is a variable: <?php echo $var; ?></p>
```

Usually should be preferred to:

```
echo "<p>This is a variable: $var</p>";
```

In general, you should avoid mixing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into your PHP code unless it's in a template or view file. Just remember there are a lot of inexperienced coders out there and you shouldn't imitate everything you see.

It's better to inject PHP into your HTML, not the other way around.

Answer (score 9):

It means exactly the same thing as when we echo HTML: that text will be sent to the browser. What the browser does with it is independent of what PHP does.

Answer (score 0):

With your given statement,

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function(){
      blah blah blah
      });
      </script>"; // You had a non useful " above
```

The output on the page will only be:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function(){
      blah blah blah
      });
      </script>
```

It won't execute the function.

Comment: There is a contradiction between your answer and the answer right below this one by @Julien Lafont

Answer (score 0):

`$(function() {})` is a shotcut to `$(document).ready(function() { })`

The content of this function will be executed when the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (a little bit before the page is completely loaded)

Comment: There is a contradiction between your answer and the answer right above this one by @hjpotter92

Comment: Yes :) And i think my answer is correct (see the jquery documentation or this exemple http://jsfiddle.net/wSaGw/ )